# “Select by color” and “draw path from selection” in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, images, shapes, svg, selections

I imported an image to Inkscape. Now I'd like to select all those regions that have the same (or to a certain degree similar) color. From this selection I'd like to draw a path (to which I can add a border or background color).

I'd like to generate an object, that has the exact dimensions as a certain region in an Image. How can I do this with Inkscape? I couldn't find one of the functions above, but I'm sure there in a easy way to do this.

EDIT:
The answer by Takkat looked quite promising. Unfortunately, although I turned off all smothening options, the paths do not follow the colours precisely:

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

The same things are happening, when I use other scan-modes. I couldn't find an option that follows the border of the enlarged pixels,...

Answer (score 8):

The way to generate objects by color in Inkscape would be to trace the bitmap to vector paths.

This is how I selected the color yellow of the sunflowers to add a white border to all sunflowers.

1. *File > Import* bitmap (embed) to the Inkscape canvas:

   [image] <sup>[Wikimedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Sunflowers.jpg)</sup>
2. Select the bitmap and choose *Path > Trace Bitmap...*:

   - In **Mode** tab choose *Colors*, and *Smooth*. **Do not *Stack* scans**.
   - Reduce number of Scans until the desired object is clear (here I used 6)
3. Choose *Object > Ungroup*.
4. Delete all objects of unwanted colors until only a single color is left over (imported bitmap is removed here only to better demonstrate the effect):

   [image]
5. Select the single yellow object to adjust *Stroke* or *Fill* settings to desired values (here I applied a 6 Pixel white stroke):

   [image]

---

For a higher precision of the trace (down to pixel size) we may have to scale up our source bitmap, depending on its content. The example below show a detail from above image linearly scaled by 1000% to reveal pixel blocks (*left*). Then I traced this image (*right*) with 12 color scans and without any path optimization (i.e. disable all, *Smooth, Suppress speckles, Smooth corners,* and *Optimize Path*):

[image]

We now can select all yellow objects, create a union object from these, and adjust fill and stroke (here a 10 px white stroke):

[image]

**Note:** Tracing large upscaled bitmaps will result in an immense amount of data. Your computer will need enough RAM to handle this.

Comment: I edited my question. The path are not drwan along the borders of "colour changes", but somewhere in the middle. I there a way to choose a single colour?

Answer (score 3):

Just found your question. Here is a solution based on a [Forum post](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&p=8910) by user 'loonquawl':

> You open the XML Editor (under Edit) and look for the color used (select the object on the canvas, and it gets highlighted in the XML Editor), copy the color (it is one of the values in "Style" e.g.
>   fill:#ffff00 and insert it into the Style Box in the Search Dialog (Strg F)
>
> Hit enter

I just tried this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The way pointed by @Takkat is correct, but it depends a lot of your source image.

Your source image seems a very small matrix image, like this:

[image: small image]

Using such an image, Potrace show a misleading preview: the image is too little and you need to trick a lot with the parameters in order to obtain something decent:

[image: not a good tracing!]

I suggest you to `scale` your starting image *without* applying interpolation, and saving it as *indexed* image:

[image: indexed image]

In this ways the tracing is a lot better:

[image: a better tracing]

The options used for this example are:

- Mode: colors
- Scans: 8 or 70 (note the difference)
- No smooth
- No stack scans
- Yes remove background
- In options tab, uncheck all

Comment: Should the scaling be done in a software different from Inkscape? I tried `Object / Transform / Scale` but stil it does not work (there was no option for smothening effects). I also have the Problem, that when saving the image as PDF, it becomes blurry. It seems that my PDF-viewer applies some interpolation,... To be honest, I don't want to change the size of each imported image manually in asoftware different from Inkspace. Can I somehow transform the image (its a sall PNG) to vector format (ideally, while importing the image)?

Comment: @R_User for a better control of the image the scaling should be dome with a software specific for raster images, like Gimp, Photoshop or many other (it's a basic operation). In order to automatize the process you can try with ImageMagick, for example `convert -scale 2000% little_image.png big_image.png` outputs an image which could be imported in Inkscape. For a batch processing, with a little more work you could invoke potrace command-line with the big_image (not tried yet).

Comment: @R_User Update: it seems that potrace cannot handle natively color images (Inkscape people added the support to colors through preprocessing). [Here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=11898) is an interesting topic, with a Python script for batch-tracing (not tried).

Answer (score 0):

since Inkscape 0.91 there's a feature under the Menu **Edit > Select Same** or in the right-click Context Menu when the oject is selected. Available Options are different properties of an object: *fill color, stroke color, fill+stroke color, pattern* or *object type*.

So in your example - if you reduce the number of scans, there are more objects with the same color and thus selectable.