# How to smooth frayed edges of a path with curves in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, path, path-effects

I have a given shape in a bitmap format which I am trying to convert to svg.

I have imported the bitmap, increased the size and converted into a path as described in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/25060/131492).

Unfortunately, the shape has frayed edges and does not look very smooth. I tried to use the "Path effect" "simplify! but the result is not satisfactory.

[image]
original image

[image]
how it looks in inkscape

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have forgotten to  delete the underlying original bitmap image. Is it deleted?

Comment: My goodness, you are right! Thanks! I feel stupid now, but I haven't done so much with Inkscape yet. Looks much better though, but there are still some dents in the curves that could be smoothed out.

Comment: There's far too many nodes, much more than this shape obviously needs. Get the node tool and delete the excessive nodes, tweak the rest if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want perfectly smooth curves, then auto tracing a poor quality bitmap is probably not the best way to do it.

Instead, you could manually trace over the lines of the bitmap with the Bézier tool set to apply an ellipse as the Shape in the tool options. This creates a Path Effect. Then you could alter the thickness of the Path Effect by clicking and dragging the control (the tiny little circle at the beginning of the path).

You can also adjust the shape of the ellipse applied as the path effect by editing it, using the "edit-on-canvas" option in the Path Effects panel.

Example

[image]